# VS 2015 Expired License (system date)

Tags: visual-studio, license-key, reinstall

I checked another answers about this error (Expired License), and yes, repairing helped me but after that i've got again this error...

I'm using community version of VS 2015 and earlier i didin't have this error.
[image: Pic of this error]

I noticed this error occurs when I set date to actual, but when I'm changing date to for example 14-05-2016 it just works.

Comment: isn't the community version free?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a Beta or Release Candidate build of Visual Studio 2015 installed. Possibly just a beta Update (Update 1 or Update 2). Install the latest update of Visual Studio 2015 (currently at update 2).

That should get things back to normal.